# Absolute Continuity and simple discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus

I am reading a book called Stochastic Process, Estimation, and Control, in [P.32](http://books.google.com/books?id=lMAClRYyW8QC&pg=PA32&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) it states that a function with finite simple discontinuities can still be absolutely continuous, which confused me, I remember that absolute continuity implies uniform continuity, which implies continuity. Can a right continuous function (i.e. a probability distribution function) with simple discontinuities still be absolutely continuous?

Comment: No. Absolute continuity of a function on an interval trivially implies the continuity of the function on that interval. I assume you're looking at [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=lMAClRYyW8QC&pg=PA31&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false). His definition of absolute continuity is the usual one (but his applies to non-decreasing functions only).

Comment: @DavidMitra Did the author make a mistake? The probability distribution function may not be continuous.